# excel vba to upload file to sharepoint

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I am trying to upload a folder from my C drive to a SharePoint library site. I have used the below code, which works fine when the ToPath is not a SharePoint library site but another folder from my C drive. Where am I going wrong?

```
Sub AddSharePointFiles()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String

ToPath = "https://share.name.com/site/folder/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/LibraryName/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
FromPath = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\FolderName"

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I noticed that the SharePoint URL starts with `https`. As such, you'll need to construct your UNC path as `\\share.name.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\site\library\`.

A few things to check:

- *WebClient* service is running
- The SharePoint site is trusted in *Internet Options*

Comment: This should be the selected answer.
We've been hunting this down for so long. You are amazing. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the Sharepoint path as UNC, and using the `CopyFolder` method:

```
Sub AddSharePointFiles()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    ToPath = "\\share.name.com\site\folder"
    FromPath = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\FolderName"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: No luck with that - it still says it doesn't exist

Comment: Have you included the filename with the path, in the `Destination`?

Comment: Answer edited - realised you want to copy the folder, not just a file - so try the `CopyFolder` method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was using:

```
Folder = Environ("USERPROFILE")
```

This gave me the name of the computer, then I filled the rest manually

```
Folder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Business\Administration\Documents"
```

It worked though I don´t think is an elegant solution.