# Open two last modified files in Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a script which opens the two last modified files in a sharepoint folder called "Test". These are Excel CSV files, so they should open in Excel. This is what I came up with, it seems to work for a local folder, but not for Sharepoint.

```
Sub test()

    Dim SummaryWB As Workbook
    Dim FileSys, objFile, myFolder, c As Object
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim strFilename, strFilename2
    FolderName = ("https://sharepoint.com/sites/Team/Shared%20Documents/Test")
          Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
           Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(FolderName)

    dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
        If InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".csv") > 0 Then
            If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
                dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
                strFilename2 = strFilename
                strFilename = objFile.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next objFile

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Application.PathSeparator & strFilename)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Application.PathSeparator & strFilename2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133197/excel-vba-code-to-upload-document-into-sharepoint-online-2013) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d3f83fe0-d4cb-455d-ab3c-823e1717d200/vba-script-to-add-items-to-sharepoint-online-list?forum=appsforsharepoint) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510770/excel-vba-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint)

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself correctly. I didn't want to upload something to sharepoint. I want to open the last two modified CSV files in a sharepoint folder.

Comment: The last link can assist you how to get access to share folder and solve issue with `seems to work for a local folder, but not for Sharepoint`. See there an answer with 4 votes

Comment: can this be a powershell script or c#? This script will be used on the server where SharePoint is installed or remotely? Or maybe it is for SharePoint Online, then for sure remotely and in this case we could use CSOM