# Save file on OneDrive/Sharepoint

Tags: vba, sharepoint, save, onedrive

I have the following code:

```vb
Sub TestSaves()

Dim fName, fNameNoEx, SaveName As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog

CurrPath = ActiveDocument.Path
'CurrPath = "C:\temp"
If Left(CurrPath, 4) = "http" Then
    PathSep = "/"
Else
    PathSep = "\"
End If

FileNumber = FreeFile
OutputFile = CurrPath & PathSep & "fred.txt"

MsgBox OutputFile

Open OutputFile For Output As #FileNumber

Print #FileNumber, "Hello World"
Close #FileNumber

End Sub
```

When my `CurrPath = ActiveDocument.Path` is active, I get

> run-time error 52 (bad file name or number)

In this case, CurrPath looks like:

[image: URL Path name]

When my `CurrPath = "C:\temp"` is active, it works.

I'd like to save another file in the same location as the original document, regardless of whether it's local or on OneDrive/Sharepoint.

Comment: not sure but I guess the `Open` method can only open files from the file system and not from sharpoint/https.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ So is there another method I could use?

Comment: It was just a guess, maybe someone can confirm that, or you can do some research to confirm that. But in any case what you could do is checkout the file from SharePoint to a local temp folder, edit it with your VBA code and [upload it again to sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510770/excel-vba-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint). • Or maybe [Map a network drive to a SharePoint library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53) is a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could figure out how to do it was:

1. Save my output file to a non-synced location (`Environ("temp")` in my case)
2. When I've finished writing to it and after doing `Close #FileNumber`, I reopen my file from the temp folder `Documents.Open filename:=TmpFile`
3. Then I do `ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 filename:=OutputFile, FileFormat:=wdFormatText` before closing the file again.

Slightly clunky, and I end up with a screen flash at the end of processing as the .txt opens, saves and closes (yes, I did try setting `visible:=false` on the open, but that also affects `ActiveDocument`).

But...it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are syncing the folder to your local machine using the OneDrive app then you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) to convert the OneDrive Url returned by `ActiveDocument.Path` to the local path, using the provided function like this `GetLocalPath(ActiveDocument.Path)`.

As a side note, I recommend using `ThisDocument` instead of `ActiveDocument`. So including the function, that would be `GetLocalPath(ThisDocument.Path)`

Your resulting code could look like this:

```vb
'Depends on function GetLocalPath, provided here: 
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457

Sub TestSaves()
    Dim fName, fNameNoEx, SaveName As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog

    CurrPath = GetLocalPath(ThisDocument.Path)

    FileNumber = FreeFile()
    OutputFile = CurrPath & Application.PathSeparator & "fred.txt"

    MsgBox OutputFile

    Open OutputFile For Output As #FileNumber
        Print #FileNumber, "Hello World"
    Close #FileNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah! many thanks, GWD. It works and saves me, but Sharepoint must be synced.

Comment: Don't we have anyway to ```Save.As``` directly the ```#FileNumber``` to Sharepoint, before ```Close #FileNumber```?
Given that pre steps we printed the file purely in a local path.

Comment: @navafolk, if you want to `SaveAs` directly to SharePoint then you have to use something along the lines of the other answer in this thread. You can even avoid the screen flash by creating a second instance of the word app. If you want, I can add code how to do this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, GWD. I would mean that ```SaveAs``` before ```Close #FileNumber```, even Stuart L's script works.

Comment: Hello @navafolk. Unfortunately, I don't know what you mean. The file is already saved before `Close #FileNumber` because the `Open` statement enables the `Print` statement to write directly to the disk. As already mentioned in the comments, the `Open` and `Print` statements can not manipulate/write files on a server via an URL.

Comment: understood, big thanks. I will end my research :)

Answer (score 0):

You CAN open and save files directly to SharePoint with VBA ...the file name and address needs to be a URL (such as https://[domain].sharepoint.com/sites/[foldername]/Shared Documents/[sub folder]/[filename]) AND have "?web=1" appended.