# VBA FileExists and Sharepoint

Tags: vba, sharepoint, directory, file-exists

I'm running into issues trying to pull info from files stored in Sharepoint.

Namely, FileExists isn't working and Overwrite file doesn't seem to be working either.

There was a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539245/vba-and-sharepoint-files), but few answers -> posting this question again in hopes some things have changed

My code runs like this:

```
strFileExists = Dir(Filepath & Filename)
```

And returns: File path not found -> I checked the path and even opened a file and recorded the macro to make sure it was the same file path without issue, but it appears **DIR()** is the issue.

The business dept I'm working with is entirely switching over to Sharepoint so hoping there's a straightforward solution without setting up network shares or doing C/personal/OneDrive things

Comment: There's no easy (or even only moderately complicated) solution to this problem - VBA just doesn't work with HTTP paths when it comes to finding/listing files etc.  This is going to be a big problem for all of us who need to do anything with VBA in a SharePoint/OneDrive environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate and look for files on OneDrive like this

```
Sub check_File_Exists()

Dim path As String
Dim strType As String
Dim file As Variant
Dim yourFile As String

'replace uname with your user name
    path = "C:\Users\uname\OneDrive\"
    strType = "*txt"
    yourFile = "test.txt"
    
    file = Dir(path & strType)
    Do While (file <> "")
        If file = yourFile Then
            Debug.Print ("File: " & file & " found!")
            Exit Do
        End If
        file = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Hope it helps