# VBA - Run error 76 Path not found in Excel

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I am trying to run this code but for some reason eror 76 Path not found pops up. The respected file exists in the listed directory.

```
Sub AddSharePointFiles()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    ToPath = "\\share.company.com\sites\hmw1\Shared%20Documents\Forms\AllItems.aspx"
    FromPath = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\ROSTER_BASELINE_1642279329.xlsx"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

End Sub
```

Running process breaks on line FSO.CopyFolder...Any idea what could cause an error?

Comment: \\share.company.com is indeed internet page in UNC format. Could you elaborate on solution as well please?

Comment: I've never tried it, but maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510770/excel-vba-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint - looks like it needs a username and password to prevent anyone on the planet from being able to write to your sharepoint folder.

Comment: Try `ToPath = "\\share.company.com\sites\hmw1\Shared Documents\"`  If that's a valid UNC path then it should be useable.  You're calling `CopyFolder` on a *file* though.  Would help to mention here if you're using SharePoint.  You may have more luck opening the file in Excel and then using `SaveAs` to save it to the https path. The UNC path is not a really reliable method of accessing SharePoint.