# How to Export Access Table as CSV to SharePoint Folder?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

Below code is working well.

```
Public Function exportCSV()
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Demographics", C:\Users\Documents\Demographics.csv"
End Function
```

But I want the file to be exported to SharePoint Folder instead locally. I tried using the SharePoint folder path but whenever I run, it gives me this
**2825 error: The file does not exist, or you do not have read access to the file.** I have access to the SharePoint but I am not sure why this error comes.
Please anyone could explain. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your Sharepoint path using https or UNC reference? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510770/excel-vba-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint

Comment: @June7 Yes, it is using https. Thank you for the link, I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that has worked for us is to use the following:
C:\Users[USERDIR][COMPANY SHAREPOINT][SHAREPOINT DIR] - [LIBRARY NAME]. I've made it a variable in ACCESS VBA by setting a variable to Environ$("USERNAME"). Here is a listing of all ENVIRON variables..https://www.geeksengine.com/article/ms-access-environ-function.html

Keep in mind that there is a 256 char limit on the string used.

Good Luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).