# Pasting hyperlink in textbox user form in VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I tried to paste the link of my sharepoint in the destination URL
[image: here's the reference]

but I am having this error:

[image: error]

The link I pasted is my Sharepoint link ("https://fujitsu.sharepoint.com/teams/Global-9f53b187/Migration/Forms/AllItems.aspx")

**This is the code for the 'Migration Start' button**

```
Private Sub btnMigrate_Click()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim answer As Integer

FromPath = txtPath.Value
ToPath = txtURL.Value

txtPath.BackColor = vbWhite
txtURL.BackColor = vbWhite

If txtPath.Value = "" Then

MsgBox "Enter the migration source path", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "WARNING!"
txtPath.BackColor = vbRed

ElseIf txtURL.Value = "" Then

MsgBox "Enter the destination URL", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "WARNING!"
txtURL.BackColor = vbRed

ElseIf Not IsEmpty(txtPath.Value) And Not IsEmpty(txtURL.Value) Then
Me.Hide

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

txtPath.Value = ""
txtPath.BackColor = vbWhite

txtURL.Value = ""
txtURL.BackColor = vbWhite

MsgBox "The migration was successful!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL!"
 
answer = MsgBox("Would you like to migrate again?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "QUESTION")

If answer = vbYes Then
  
  txtPath.Value = ""
  txtPath.BackColor = vbWhite

  txtURL.Value = ""
  txtURL.BackColor = vbWhite

  Migration.Show
Else
  Me.Hide
  
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you edit the question and show us the relevant codes? Also, just `runtime error` is not a good enough description of the issue - What is the error code/description and which line did it occur?

Comment: I hope the edited one is clear, thank you Raymond :)

Comment: Please include all relevant codes.

Comment: Perhaps you need to construct the UNC path as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50515195/15597936)