# Upload an Excel file to Sharepoint with VBA scripts

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, upload

I wrote a VBA script to upload my excel sheet, I don't know why it did not show any errors but whenever I refreshed the Sharepoint page, the excel file did not persist there.
Furthermore, it seems that with my current code, the whole excel workbook is supposed to be uploaded, whereas I expect to upload only "sheet2" (the workbook contains 2 sheets, named "sheet1" and "sheet2" respectively).

```
Sub UploadSharepoint()


Dim SharepointAddress As String
Dim LocalAddress As String
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object

' Sharepoint location path
SharepointAddress = "\\https:\\XXX.sharepoint.com\sites\my_folder\Test"

 ' Excel file path
LocalAddress = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FS.FileExists(LocalAddress) Then
FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress
End If
Set objNet = Nothing
Set FS = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: The only thing I change according to your suggestion is: LocalAddress = ActiveWorkbook.FullName, but there's still nothing

Comment: may be a solution here, to do with https: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510770/excel-vba-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint

Comment: Have you thought about using Environ$("OneDriveCommercial") or Environ$("OneDrive") and saving the file locally?

Comment: Aside from it not working: Your code is just a file-copy. If you want to only copy `Sheet2`, then you're going to need to create an Excel file that only contains `Sheet2` and then either `SaveAs` the file to the SharePoint address, or `SaveAs` locally and then file-copy it to SharePoint.

Comment: I tried with the script from this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510770/excel-vba-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint) but then it turns out to be "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: Have you followed all the points specifically in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50515195/7446760?

Comment: Yes but still did not work